# jQuery with ASP.NET - Prevent Link from Scrolling to Top of Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am building a .NET application that uses a GridView control. I am using a LinkButton control to allow the user to enter Edit mode. Whenever the user clicks this button, it does allow him to edit an entry as it should; however, it also scrolls back to the top of the page. Obviously, this is not ideal; however, I cannot simply use event.PreventDefault() to eliminate this behavior.

I have assigned the class "gridActionLinks" to the controls. When the user clicks the need, I need the link action to occur, and then the scrolling. As it now stands, it scrolls down to the link, and then executes the default link behavior (including going to the top of the page). Is there a way around this? That is, is there a way for the link behavior to execute first, followed by the scrolling?

Thanks much!

The script:

```
  $(".gridActionLinks").click(function (event) {      


        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
        }, 100
        );


    });
```

A snippet of the aspx:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
          <ItemTemplate>
              <asp:LinkButton ID="detailsLink" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument="" Tooltip="Edit Record" CausesValidation="False" CssClass="gridActionLinks"><img src="../img/detailsIcon.png" /></asp:LinkButton>
                         <asp:LinkButton ID="deleteLink" CommandName="Delete" runat="server" Tooltip="Delete Record" CssClass="gridActionLinks" CausesValidation="False"><img src="../img/deleteIcon.png" /></asp:LinkButton>
          </ItemTemplate>
          <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="insertLink" CommandName="Update" runat="server" Tooltip="Save" CausesValidation="False"><img src="../img/saveIcon.png" /></asp:LinkButton>
                         <asp:LinkButton ID="cancelLink" CommandName="Cancel" runat="server" Tooltip="Cancel" CausesValidation="False"><img src="../img/cancelIcon.png" /></asp:LinkButton>
          </EditItemTemplate>
          <FooterTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="insertLink" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Tooltip="New Entry"><img src="../img/saveIcon.png" /></asp:LinkButton>
                         <asp:LinkButton ID="cancelLink" runat="server" CommandName="CancelEntry" Tooltip="Cancel"><img src="../img/cancelIcon.png" /></asp:LinkButton>          </FooterTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
```

Some of the aspx.cs:

```
protected void vehicleGrid_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            vehicleGrid.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;


                this.initialize ();

            }

     private void initialize()
        {
            try {
            using (fleetModel context = new fleetModel())
            {

                vehicleGrid.DataSource = context.vehicles.SortBy("renewal").ToList();
                vehicleGrid.DataBind();
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your link buttons are marked `runat="server"` they will generate a postback event and the page will refresh.  If you wish to keep the page position after postback, use a [page directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8syafc7.aspx):

```
<%@ Page Language="c#" CodeBehind="MyPage.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="false" Inherits="MyPage" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack="true"%>
```

or [set it in code behind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback(v=vs.110).aspx) with

```
this.MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack = true;
```